# Kinesis Client Library, pre-created DynamoDB Tables

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-kinesis

I am using the Kinesis Client Library version 2.x

It is expected that issues like leasing of shards as well as rebalancing  are going to be tackled through DynamoDB usage.

Following the Principle of least privilege I do not want my consumer applications to have the option to create DynamoDB tables dynamically. Instead I prefer resources to be created upfront using the preferred IAC tool and afterwards create some fine tuned roles.

Is there a way to skip the consumer based DynamoDB table creation? Am I covered If I just create the expected DynamoDB tables per shards and future shards (proactively in case of on demand scale up) or is there a random Pattern on the names of the DynamoDB tables the consumer library creates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After checking the [source code](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-client/blob/cce05bf4fd03eed007bf6c51203f3cccc189c92a/amazon-kinesis-client/src/main/java/software/amazon/kinesis/leases/dynamodb/DynamoDBLeaseRefresher.java) of amazon-kinesis-client only one Table is created and this one has the name of the application name that you give on the scheduler.

So the above is possible.